# Is there any downside for using a leading double slash to inherit the protocol in a URL? i.e. src="//domain.example"

Tags: http, url, https, url-scheme

I have a stylesheet that loads images from an external domain and I need it to load from `https://` from secure order pages and `http://` from other pages, based on the current URL. I found that starting the URL with a double slash inherits the current protocol. Do all browsers support this technique?

HTML ex:

```
<img src="//cdn.domain.example/logo.png" />
```

CSS ex:

```
.class { background: url(//cdn.domain.example/logo.png); }
```

Comment: does this slow down the site???

Comment: there's no reason this should have any impact on performance, except in the cases that Meder listed below in her answer.

Comment: Looks like I was on to something.  A few months ago, Google Developers started using this convention on their Hosted Javascript libraries page https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide

Comment: What if such a HTML file is loaded locally (opened directly with the browser)? Looks like Firefox (28 in this case) then does not load the remote resource. Makes sense, because then HTTP is not the parent protocol. But that would be a disadvantage, in my opinion.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

If the browser supports [RFC 1808 Section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1808#section-4), [RFC 2396 Section 5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-5.2), or [RFC 3986 Section 5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2), then it will indeed use the page URL's scheme for references that begin with "//".

Comment: is this supported on all major browsers?  (IE7, IE8, FF, Chrome, Safari)

Comment: Considering that the first RFC to describe it, RFC 1808, was written 15 years ago, and URL references are key to website functionality, I think it is safe to say that pretty much all major browsers do support it by now.  But the only way to know for sure is to simply try it yourself and see what happens.

Comment: This question was linked from someone asking a similar question, and I found it in RFC 1630 the year before (stated differently, but still allowing the format in question). It could well have been in one form or other of the document that used to be at `ftp://info.cern.ch/pub/www/doc/http-spec.txt` starting in 1991, should anyone have an archive copy.

Comment: "2014.12.17: Now that SSL is encouraged for everyone and doesn’t have performance concerns, this technique is now an anti-pattern. If the asset you need is available on SSL, then always use the https:// asset." (quote quoted from http://stackoverflow.com/a/27999789 )

Comment: @joonas.fi That reasoning is sophomoric. SSL still does have performance impacts and is unneeded in a great number of applications. I prefer to use it, sure, but I wouldn't want that enforced in, for instance, code that I deploy.

Answer (score 67):

When used on a `link` or `@import`, IE7/IE8 will download the file twice per http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Update from 2014:

> Now that SSL is [encouraged for everyone](https://www.eff.org/encrypt-the-web-report) and [doesn’t have performance concerns](https://istlsfastyet.com/), **this technique is now an anti-pattern**. If the asset you need is available on SSL, then **always** use the `https://` asset.

Comment: @EricLaw is that fixed in IE9 regardless of rendering mode or only in Standards Mode and still broken in Quirks Mode?

Comment: I'm almost positive that this was fixed in all modes in the lookahead scanner. Have you seen otherwise somewhere?

Comment: SSL certainly *does* have a performance impact. The EFF doesn't write server-server interfaces, and that other site has little technical expertie. Further, it is an anti-pattern to assume that the vendor of a web-site will enforce such restrictions. Thus, people write CSS and javascript applications should not bank on the protocol question.

Answer (score 65):

One downside occurs if your URLs are viewed outside the context of a web page. For example, an email message sitting in an email client (say, Outlook) effectively has no URL, and when you're viewing a message containing a protocol-relative URL, there is no obvious protocol context at all (the message itself is independent of the protocol used to fetch it, whether it's POP3, IMAP, Exchange, uucp or whatever) so the URL has no protocol to be relative to. I've not investigated compatibility with email clients to see what they do when presented with a missing protocol handler - I'm guessing that most will take a guess at http. Apple Mail refuses to let you enter a URL without a protocol. It's analogous to the way that relative URLs do not work in email because of a similarly missing context.

Similar problems could occur in other non-HTTP contexts such as in tweets, SMS messages, Word documents etc.

The more general explanation is that anonymous protocol URLs cannot work in isolation; there **must** be a relevant context. In a typical web page it's thus fine to pull in a script library that way, but any external links should always specify a protocol. I did try one simple test: `//stackoverflow.com` maps to `file:///stackoverflow.com` in all browsers I tried it in, so they *really* don't work by themselves.

Comment: This is a really good point, I was actually thinking about this as I fell asleep last night. Another issue is that the `https` or `http` version may not actually be available, you can't always assume that it is.

Comment: Outside of a browser you're on your own, so to speak. There's no saying if the email or other client knows about javascript or css etc. So this is pretty much a moot point about relative urls?

Comment: Not a moot point. Many e-mail clients support JS and browsers certainly can when loading from `file://`. It is a minor usecase, but when it comes up it is important.

Comment: I do wish there were a way to specify _use http unless the current url is https, in which case use https_, rather than specifying _use the same protocol that the current pages was loaded with_, which is effectively what `//` is.

Comment: If you specify an e.g. `<base href="https://www.google.com">`, you can view the content outside the web-side. either `<img src="//www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png">` or `<img src="images/srpr/logo11w.png">`

Comment: @zig - unless you are using a mail client that strips the head tag from emails, like hotmail does... A base tag can also make URL fragments act incorrectly, turning them into absolute external links instead of internal ones.

Answer (score 3):

The reason could be to provide portable web pages. If the outer page is not transported encrypted (http), why should the linked scripts be encrypted? This seems to be an unnecessary performance loss. In case, the outer page is securely transported encrypted (https), then the linked content should be encrypted, too. If the page is encrypted, the linked content not, IE seems to issue a **Mixed Content** warning. The reason is that an attacker can manipulate the scripts on the way. See http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Browser/MixedContent/Default.html?o=1 for a longer discussion.

The [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) campaign from the EFF suggests to use https whenever possible. We have the server capacity these days to serve web pages always encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness. This was mentioned in another thread:

> [The "two forward slashes" are a common shorthand for "whatever protocol is being used right now"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9646435/1667461)

```
if (plain http environment) {
    use 'http://example.com/my-resource.js'
} else {
    use 'https://example.com/my-resource.js'
}
```

Please check the full thread.

Answer (score -2):

It seems to be a pretty common technique now. There is no downside, it only helps to unify the protocol for all assets on the page so should be used wherever possible.