# Browser support for URLs beginning with double slash

Tags: url, browser, cross-browser

I've recently seen a few links used without a protocol. It didn't seem too difficult to understand - I think it's a great idea and pretty intuitive.

For those of you unaware, using a URL like `//example.com/script.js` will point to either `http://example.com/script.js` or `https://example.com/script.js` depending on whether or not the URL originates from a **http** or **https** URL. Including http scripts or images from a https page can be a security concern, for example, so this solves that without the need for protocol detection in your code.

My question is, what sort of browser/OS support is there for it? Is it safe to use in production? It would certainly make things a bit easier.

Simple example and test:
http://codetester.org/916c6916

EDIT:
Just a follow up that I've been using this for my company's ad server in production for many things without issue for a couple years now.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659345/is-there-any-downside-for-using-a-leading-double-slash-to-inherit-the-protocol-in --- In short, it's in the RFC specification so it _should_ be supported by all major browsers.

Comment: @Keith Thanks, that's good and all, but looking through the RFC specs, I don't actually see anything about this beginning double slash thing. Was hoping to find some definitive browser testing already done. :)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

This behavior was part of [RFC 1808](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1808#section-4) (Section 4) which is about 16 years old, so every major browser should (and does) support this.

Sadly, there's [a bug with IE7 and -8](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) that will make them download the resources twice if a protocol-relative URL is used on a `link` or `@import` - which shouldn't be a big problem, but is ugly and should be kept in mind.

Comment: This is an old post, but I also wanted to say it's not a good practice at all. Recently I had some trouble on one of our customers admin dashboard. The URL `//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js` was not found and the library not loaded. I then try to load `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js` and see an error page. I suspect a proxy or VPN or firewall security configuration they set internally. After updating the URL to use the `https` protocol, everything works fine.

Answer (score 4):

If you are developing on a local machine there's possibility it will fail with `src="file://host.com/filename".`

In this situation you need to specify scheme explicitly: `http://host.com/filename` or `https://host.com/filename`.

Comment: When developing offline you should use a local server anyway, which would make the URL "http://localhost".