# What's the difference between // and https://?

Tags: url

As most of you know, when using an external library via a CDN, let's say Google, the url often looks something like this.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When using this on a live site, this works perfectly. However, locally it doesn't. Changing `//` to `https://` does the trick. (Didn't test with `http`.)

So, what's the catch, and what's the difference?

Comment: This thing even has its own tag on SO: [tag:protocol-relative].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`//` takes the current used protocol. Mainly `https` or `http`, but also any other protocol supported by the browser, such as `ftp`.

If you're visitig a site via `https` the used URL for your `//`-resource is `https` too.

See also [Browser support for URLs beginning with double slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785442/browser-support-for-urls-beginning-with-double-slash)

Comment: That's the catch. If you open an html file with `file:///` then any urls referenced as `//` will be tried to be loaded and needs to be accessible with `//`.

Comment: Referring to fejese's answer: If you have a local webserver and are loading `http://localhost` for example it should work. It'll not work with `file:///`