# Parsing the urls in sitemap with different url format using sitemap spider in scrapy, python

Tags: python, web-scraping, sitemap, scrapy

I am using sitemap spider in scrapy, python.
The sitemap seems to have unusual format with '//' in front of urls:

```
<url>
    <loc>//www.example.com/10/20-baby-names</loc>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>//www.example.com/elizabeth/christmas</loc>
 </url>
```

## myspider.py

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import SitemapSpider
from myspider.items import *

class MySpider(SitemapSpider):
    name = "myspider"
    sitemap_urls = ["http://www.example.com/robots.txt"]

    def parse(self, response):
        item = PostItem()           
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//title/text()').extract()

        return item
```

I am getting this error:

```
raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
    exceptions.ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: //www.example.com/10/20-baby-names
```

How can I manually parse the url using sitemap spider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the nicest and cleanest solution would be to add a downloader middleware which changes the malicious URLs without the spider noticing.

```
import re
import urlparse
from scrapy.http import XmlResponse
from scrapy.utils.gz import gunzip, is_gzipped
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import SitemapSpider

# downloader middleware
class SitemapWithoutSchemeMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        if isinstance(spider, SitemapSpider):
            body = self._get_sitemap_body(response)

            if body:
                scheme = urlparse.urlsplit(response.url).scheme
                body = re.sub(r'<loc>\/\/(.+)<\/loc>', r'<loc>%s://\1</loc>' % scheme, body)    
                return response.replace(body=body)

        return response

    # this is from scrapy's Sitemap class, but sitemap is
    # only for internal use and it's api can change without
    # notice
    def _get_sitemap_body(self, response):
        """Return the sitemap body contained in the given response, or None if the
        response is not a sitemap.
        """
        if isinstance(response, XmlResponse):
            return response.body
        elif is_gzipped(response):
            return gunzip(response.body)
        elif response.url.endswith('.xml'):
            return response.body
        elif response.url.endswith('.xml.gz'):
            return gunzip(response.body)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I see it correctly, you could (for a quick solution) override the default implementation of `_parse_sitemap` in `SitemapSpider`. It's not nice, because you will have to copy a lot of code, but should work.
You'll have to add a method to generate a URL with scheme.

```
"""if the URL starts with // take the current website scheme and make an absolute
URL with the same scheme"""
def _fix_url_bug(url, current_url):
    if url.startswith('//'):
           ':'.join((urlparse.urlsplit(current_url).scheme, url))
       else:
           yield url

def _parse_sitemap(self, response):
    if response.url.endswith('/robots.txt'):
        for url in sitemap_urls_from_robots(response.body)
            yield Request(url, callback=self._parse_sitemap)
    else:
        body = self._get_sitemap_body(response)
        if body is None:
            log.msg(format="Ignoring invalid sitemap: %(response)s",
                    level=log.WARNING, spider=self, response=response)
            return

        s = Sitemap(body)
        if s.type == 'sitemapindex':
            for loc in iterloc(s):
                # added it before follow-test, to allow test to return true
                # if it includes the scheme (yet do not know if this is the better solution)
                loc = _fix_url_bug(loc, response.url)
                if any(x.search(loc) for x in self._follow):
                    yield Request(loc, callback=self._parse_sitemap)
        elif s.type == 'urlset':
            for loc in iterloc(s):
                loc = _fix_url_bug(loc, response.url) # same here
                for r, c in self._cbs:
                    if r.search(loc):
                        yield Request(loc, callback=c)
                        break
```

This is just a general idea and untested. So it could both either totally not work or there could be syntax errors. Please respond via comments, so I can improve my answer.

The sitemap you are trying to parse, seems to be wrong. From RFC a missing scheme [is perfectly fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785442/browser-support-for-urls-beginning-with-double-slash), but sitemaps [require URLs to begin with a scheme](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#locdef).

Comment: Not going to work, `iterloc` is the same module as `SitemapSpider` and redefining it like this would not change anything. I was looking into this - a `mock` is probably something that can help.

Comment: Can you Elaborate a bit? If he has an instance `MySpider` running, shouldn't the `iterloc` method of `MySpider` be called? I have the feeling you're referencing to a problem with polymorphism in my idea?

Comment: The problem is `iterloc` is not a method in the `SitemapSpider` - it is a separate function outside of the class, but in the same module.

Comment: By the way, probably overriding `_parse_sitemap()` internal method and fixing the urls before sending the requests is a better option..check this out. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe can you give some example for overriding _parse_sitemap() to fix the urls before sending request?

Answer (score 1):

I used the trick by @alecxe to parse the urls within the spider. I made it work but not sure if it is the best way to do it.

```
from urlparse import urlparse
import re 
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.utils.response import body_or_str
from example.items import *

class ExampleSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "example"
    start_urls = ["http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml"]

    def parse(self,response):
        nodename = 'loc'
        text = body_or_str(response)
        r = re.compile(r"(<%s[\s>])(.*?)(</%s>)" % (nodename, nodename), re.DOTALL)
        for match in r.finditer(text):
            url = match.group(2)
            if url.startswith('//'):
                url = 'http:'+url
                yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_page)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        # print response.url
        item = PostItem()   

        item['url'] = response.url
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
        return item
```