# Why in this simple Angular example it seems that Angular is not defined?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am absolutly new in AngularJS and I have the following problem.

Yesterday a runned this very simple first AngularJS application download from a tutorial amd it worked fine.

The application is composed by the following 2 files:

1) **index.htm**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" ng-app="angularApp">
    <head>
        <title>Introduction to AngularJS</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <!-- load bootstrap and fontawesome via CDN -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <style>
            html, body
            {
                font-size: 1.1em;
            }
        </style>

        <!-- load angular via CDN -->
        <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">AngularJS</a>
                </div>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <div class="container">

            <div ng-controller="mainController">

                <h1>Hello world!</h1>

            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

2) And the included **app.js** file:

```
// MODULE
var angularApp = angular.module('angularApp', []);

// CONTROLLERS
angularApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

}]);
```

As you can see in the **index.htm** file include the local **app.js** file, **AngularJS** framework by:

```
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
```

and **BootStrap** CSS framework by:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Yesterday it worked fine but today when I try to open the **index.htm** file into my browser I obtain that BootStrap is not used (there are not CSS settings) and into the FireBug console I obtain this error message:

```
ReferenceError: angular is not defined
var angularApp = angular.module('angularApp', []);
```

It seems that can't see Angular framework and BootStrap also if there are correctly included and I can open in the browser the following links:

```
//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular.min.js

//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

and see the code of Angular and BootStrap.

So why? What could be the problem? Yesteday it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open it via a URL - e.g. `http://localhost/myapp/index.htm`, not using the `file:///` protocol

You have either double clicked the file and opened it, or opened it with your browser's file -> open option in which case it will be opened using `file:///` and the URL to bootstrap - `//netdna......` will not resolve as it will look for it in the local file system.

If you don't have a webserver, then simply change the following:

```
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

to this:

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Comment: It seems to me so strange. To run a page that use JavaScript I don't need to use it inside a web server. Infact on this machine I have not Apache installed and yesterday the example runned well

Comment: The '//' prefix is not necessarily the file:// moniker.  It means that the load should follow whatever the page load used.  i.e. if the page loaded as http, use http; if the page loaded as https, use https.

Comment: @codenoire - if the OP loaded the page with the `file:///` protocol, it is the only circumstance in which case bootstrap would not load (unless of course, the OP doesn't have a network connection).

Comment: @AndreaNobili - the only way this page would have ever worked (if you have always used `//` instead of the fully qualified `http(s)://` in front of your references to your bootstrap/angular libraries is if it was loaded over `http` and not over `file:///`

Comment: The stuff for angular and bootstrap are on a CDN.  Those urls **won't** work with a '//' prefix if the page is loaded with the file:// protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You are using url

```
https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular.min.js
```

If you are on a development machine, usually it will be using the http moniker, **NOT** https.  The browser won't load from the URL above because of that, as it's a security concern.  Change it to 'http' or go back to the '//' prefix.

Comment: If you look in the code I use //code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular.min.js

Comment: You should look here as well.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785442/browser-support-for-urls-beginning-with-double-slash

Comment: @codenoire - the `http` version of that CDN URL simply `307` redirects to `https` so this does not make a difference. As long as the OP puts in a fully qualified URL with the `http(s):` prefix, then he'll be fine. The whole "it was working fine yesterday" implies that the OP opened up the app via a URL (e.g. `http://localhost/myapp`) and today is opening it up via `file:///index.htm`