# When I copy a jQuery UI example to run locally it loses some visual styling

Tags: jquery-ui

I was trying to run the Connected List example on this page:
[jQuery UI #Connected Lists](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists)

But when I copy the html and the style.css file into a local
directory and open up the html, I don't get the highlight color and border as seen in the picture

What I get from the URL
[image: From The URL]

What I get when run locally
[image: From Local]

In the html code, the first column has the class "ui-state-default" and the second column is "ui-state-highlight"

The drag-and-drop functionality is still all there, just not the styling.

Is there some initialization of the demo environment that isn't included in the supplied code?

Comment: Did you copy the two style sheets referenced in the code, as well as the local stuff...The background color comes from the referenced jquery.ui.css file.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @MarkSchultheiss!  You were right, and I had copied the local code, but didn't think I needed to copy the other one, but the problem is explained here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785442/browser-support-for-urls-beginning-with-double-slash] in the answer at the bottom given by @MatasVaitkevicius

Answer (score 0):

The answer lay in the reference to the jQuery .css file given here:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

The problem is the reference starting with the double //.  I got it to work by adding https: before the double quotes, or copying it locally and removing the //.  The problem is the // does not correctly interpret the file:// access.  It is discussed here: [Browser support for URLs beginning with double slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785442/browser-support-for-urls-beginning-with-double-slash) see the answer from @Matas Vaitkevicius