# My <nav> element isn't showing up in IE7 at all

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

The website is http://goo.gl/e2Ipj

I cant get the nav (the six links at the top) to show up in IE7 at all, i have tried playing with height and position and z-index and nothing makes it show.

I am also using:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

To make sure the nav element is displayed correctly, as it's HTML5. I am also using header/footer and they display fine.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Why is there a `//` in front of the src? Surely that will kill it.

Comment: @JoshuaM - No, that should be fine. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659345/is-there-any-downside-for-using-a-leading-double-slash-to-inherit-the-protocol-i

Comment: someone is missing a protocol... put http: at the beginning of that source attribute

Comment: @JoshuaM `//` mimics the current pages protocol, http etc

Comment: @derekerdmann, Oh, okay then. Always good to find new stuff out!

Comment: everyday is a skool day (for me anyway...) - what happens if you DO put the protocol in?

Comment: Can you show us the HTML code, maybe as a jsfiddle?

Comment: @LeonardChallis I don't know where the error is so don't know what to include into the jsfiddle. There is a link to the live site on the first line though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<nav>` is being rendered above the page (31 pixels above it, to be exact). This is because IE7 does not support `height: inherit`. In fact it doesn't support `inherit` at all.

Set the height explicitly, and the navigation pops right into place.

Comment: But i haven't used `height: inherit`?

Comment: Then what, pray tell, is this? `<div class="wrapper960" style="height:inherit;">` on line 84.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Stupid me putting CSS outside the stylesheet! That fixed it.