# Where is the double slash URL style legal? ( "//connect.facebook.net")

Tags: url

I've seen this style of URLs lately:

```
//connect.facebook.net/
```

I imagine this means: If the current page is http, go to `http://connect.facebook.com/`, if it's https, go to `https://connect.facebook.com/`. In which browsers / versions is it legal? When was it introduced into the standard?

Comment: first answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659345/is-there-any-downside-for-using-a-leading-double-slash-to-inherit-the-protocol-i : it was implemented in an RFC 15 years ago, so probably all of them.

Comment: @arxanas Ha! I found one a year older, do I get a prize? ;)

Comment: @JonHanna yes a lovely upvote from me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Current standard §4.2. RFC 3986.

Originally given in RFC 1808, 1995 which was the first RFC defining relative URIs specifically, though RFC 1630, 1994 gave a slightly different definition, though still allowing that.

There were earlier documents than those RFCs, so if someone could find an archived version of the document that was once at `ftp://info.cern.ch/pub/www/doc/http-spec.txt` (first version having been in 1991) then they could perhaps give an earlier date if said document gives such a form, but it requires a bit more historian work than I can do right now.

Essentially, they've always been allowed, certainly since there was anything we could call a standard, that standard allowed it.