# Storing an array of times and displaying tv shows using jquerys nextUntil

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page that I want to scrape that has the following format:

```
<ul>
<li>7 pm</li>
<li>8 pm</li>
<ul>

<h6 id="7 pm">7 pm</h6>
<div class="show">My TV Show #1</div>
<div class="show">My TV Show #2</div>
<div class="show">My TV Show #3</div>
<h6 id="8 pm">8 pm</h6>
```

how can I get it to display the time and then all shows for that time?

I have attempted to store the time in any array with success but I'm getting stuck when it comes to actually doing something with the array of times.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>jQuery PHP Page Scape</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("document").ready(function() {
            var times = new Array();

            $.ajax({
                url: "curl.php",
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function(data) {
                    $(data).find('.wnt-top-r ul li').each(function(i, item) {
                        times.push($(item).text());
                        $('#content').append(times[i]);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="content"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: display array array initialization

Comment: Duplicate IDs = invalid markup.

Comment: Multiple IDs are also invalid markup.

Comment: What do you want to do with `times` array ?

Comment: @Brian First You should add `http:` or `https:` in front of your google hosted jquery CDN url.

Comment: @JakeRow123, why? // is perfectly acceptable. https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide

Comment: @Aktee try saving this on a blank page and opening it in a browser: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>$("document").ready(function() { alert('hello world'); });</script>`. It won't work, not in the latest version of firefox at least. I believe google cdn left it like that to alert users that there is both a http and https version.

Comment: @JakeRow123, it works. Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659345/is-there-any-downside-for-using-a-leading-double-slash-to-inherit-the-protocol-i

Comment: @Aktee that's odd, I can't get it to work in either ff or chrome. Perhaps it's a setting on my computer or browser/s that are causing the issue then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your markup. This is not possible/optimized for how your layout is done.

First, a valid HTML id name must start with a letter.

Second, there can only be 1 same ID, no duplicates.

Third, a space is not a valid character in ID name.

Since your markup is invalid, here's a suggestion.

```
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li data-showtime="19">7pm</li>
        <li data-showtime="20">8pm</li>
        <li data-showtime="21">9pm</li>
    </ul>

    <h6 class="time-title time-19" data-showtime="19">7pm</h6>
    <div class="show time-19">My TV Show 1</div>
    <div class="show time-19">My TV Show 2</div>
    <div class="show time-19">My TV Show 3</div>
    <div class="show time-19">My TV Show 4</div>
    <div class="show time-19">My TV Show 5</div>
    <h6 class="time-title time-20" data-showtime="20">8pm</h6>
    <div class="show time-20">My TV Show 5</div>
    <div class="show time-20">My TV Show 6</div>
</div>
```

​
and the script:

```
  $(function() {
        showtime = {};
        $("#container").find("h6.time-title").each(function() {
            var t = $(this);
            var d = t.data();
            showtime[d.showtime] = {};
            showtime[d.showtime]['caption'] = t.text();

            var tempshows = [];
            $(".show.time-"+d.showtime).each(function() {
                showname = $(this).text();
                tempshows.push(showname)
            })

            showtime[d.showtime]['shows'] = tempshows;
        })

console.log(showtime);

    })
​
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FhKAh/1/

In case you cannot change the markup and have to deal with this, try this:

```
showtime = {};
$("h6").each(function() {
    h6 = $(this);

    var tempshow = [];
    h6.nextUntil("h6").each(function() {
        tempshow.push($(this).text())
    });


    showtime[h6.text()] = {};
    showtime[h6.text()]['shows'] = tempshow;


});

    console.log(showtime);
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CGyBK/