# Why isn't this jquery code working with for loop and $.get

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
          $.get("http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_get",function(data,status){
      //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
   }
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Send an HTTP GET request to a page and get the result back</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's no such thing as `int` in JavaScript.

Comment: You should always look at the output of the JavaScript error console and, if it doesn't help you, post it here with your question. In this case it likely would have made your mistake very obvious.

Comment: once you resolve `int` issue... read up on cross domain ajax

Comment: It still not working. And I am using w3schools.com tryit editor.

Comment: @Miszy, then please feel free to cry in private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax in faulty, try to open your file in for example Chrome Developer's Tools: you'll get a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`. This is because JavaScript isnt' C: you cannot define a variable to be a type, like you do on line 9, you need to define it using the `var` keyword like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      $.get("http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_get",function(data,status){
  //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
```

Running that on the editor of w3schools work for me.

Comment: Why do you think the `src` attribute is faulty? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659345/is-there-any-downside-for-using-a-leading-double-slash-to-inherit-the-protocol-i

Comment: its not going in a for loop.

Comment: @Miszy: I wasn't aware he was running it from the w3schools editor, so I thought he missed out on the `http:` part of the src attribute, when I ran it as local file. Being a newbie in webdevelopment and all, I was clearly wrong...

Comment: @user658911: what do you mean?

Comment: The for loop is not working and not requesting the $.get parameter 10 times.

Comment: The `for`-loop is missing the closing brace.