# Tips on loading external css and javascript over https

Tags: javascript, css, https

When setting up a site to run over `https://` is there a way to stop the page from blocking any external css or javascript loaded from standard `http://`.

Some of the external files are under the same domain, so could be called via `https://`, but some are from another domain that has no secure connection available.

Comment: Just make sure everything is over SSL. There is a reason it would not load or at least warn the user you know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There shouldn't be. Such security measures are in place for good reason.

Even if you could remove them, doing so would be a very bad idea.

A man-in-the-middle attack would allow the JS or CSS (which can have embedded JS via various browser extensions) to be substituted.

This would allow an attacker to run any JS they liked on the page.

That JS could grab any data from the page and send it to the attacker.

The page would not be secure.

Copy the assets somewhere that you can access them over HTTPS.

Comment: K. I understand that now. That being the case, on the external domain would a self certified SSL certificate work or would this cause a warning message to be displayed from the browser?

Comment: It would cause a warning, since the chain of trust couldn't be verified.

Comment: Darn. Think I need to have a rethink. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your links without using scheme (like "//example.com/styles/mystyle.css").

[See this questions for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659345/is-there-any-downside-for-using-a-leading-double-slash-to-inherit-the-protocol-i)

In case some external content is unavailable via HTTPS, you can make a HTTPS proxy on your server (with some sort of caching and ACL if you like).

Comment: Interesting suggestion. Do you know of any examples I this I can take a look at please?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no pre-made samples for you, but you can write a simple script for that on your favourite  programming language.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll have a play.