# Using // instead of prototcol

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, protocols, require

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any downside for using a leading double slash to inherit the protocol in a URL? i.e. src=“//domain.com”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659345/is-there-any-downside-for-using-a-leading-double-slash-to-inherit-the-protocol-i)

I have seen the following logic in many places, f.ex the analytics script:

```
script.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
    '://example.com/cdn.js';
```

But to my knowledge, you could just as well do:

```
script.src = '//example.com/cdn.js';
```

and it should use whatever protocol that is currently used. Or am I missing something? What is considered "best practice"?

I’m not looking for browser compatibility answers, google already recommends `//` for CDN scripts so that shouldn’t be the case here.

Here’s a fiddle, but it doesn’t really say much more than it seems to work in this setup: http://jsfiddle.net/6ZGyb/

Comment: Already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/q/4659345/861940

Comment: @Bruno Not really the answer I was looking for (browser support), surely there must be another reason for google to use the protocol testing technique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A bit of background:**

The additional JavaScript `protocol` wrapper is usually there to assure all browsers' support for such `relative path` `URL`s. **You're right to assume most current browsers handle such URLs properly** anyway, however for the sake of being able to sleep with a rested mind, it's still generally considered a good practice to assume **not all user-agents** accessing your web pages are as savvy as we'd expect them to be (or, supporting [RFC 1808](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1808.txt) Section 4, [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1808.txt) Section 5.2, or [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) Section 5.2 as already mentioned in [**Is there any downside for using a leading double slash to inherit the protocol in a URL?** thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4659345/861940) as @Bruno pointed out in the comment)

**Compatibility concerns:**

Imagine a scenario where contents containing such relative paths are accessible *'out-of-context'*, e.g. in a email client. In this case such relative paths might be parsed to their fully qualified paths the wrong way and cause all kinds of problems, from users not being able to see contents properly, to accessing contents they really shouldn't be. To avoid any such issues, **use of relative paths should always be limited to in-context cases where the parser of the parent document (opener application) can determine the complete absolute path to the resource in question.** You should only expect relative paths to work properly when they'll be accessed by same or compatible protocol.

**Security concerns:**

Another possible concern that was raised is:

> ***Could such relative protocol URLs be exploited in any way by accessing (parsed URL) parent document contents by various exchange
>   protocols, and if such JavaScript wrapper serves a purpose of
>   deflecting such access.***

The (long) list of **[official IANA registered URL schemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Official_IANA-registered_schemes)** suggests there's a lot of potentially worrying exchange protocols that could be used by exploiters, however **JavaScript wouldn't do much anything on user-agents that don't have support for JavaScript (or is disabled by user)**. My answer would, with that in mind, have to be - **no (for the *'JavaScript protecting access using other protocols'* part)**.

**As for the remaining part of the raised concern** (*'could such relative protocol URLs be exploited in any way'*), the answer depends on how well this was considered when setting up the web server serving any such contents, does it even support/handle such requests (if it doesn't then it's a non-issue), and what possible vectors of attack/content theft were considered before deployment. In other words, **it's a web server administration problem and certainly not something web designers/programmers could/should answer.** Each end-user accessible protocol should have its own set of security protocols on top of it.

Comment: Google recommends the `//` for their CDN scripts so that seems unlikely. Are you sure it’s not just a test to ensure you are not using some other shady protocol, like `file://`?

Comment: Locally hosted files is definitely one reason you'd use this Javascript. Using a protocol-relative URL here would end up pointing you to `file://example.com/cdn.js`, which will not load properly.

Comment: Are there any user-agents that don't properly handle `//`-style URIs?