# display bootstrap modal on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

So I've got an application where the user selects a category from a dropdown. I want to give them the option to create a new category if they want, so the last option in the dropdown is "Create Your Own"

I can get the event of them selecting the last one by using:

```
        $("#category").change(function () {
            selection = $(this).val();
            if (selection == -1) {
                alert("create new one");
            }
        });
```

This works as expected with no issues. However, when I try to replace `alert("create new one");` with `$("#myModal").modal('show');` I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'modal'
```

I am linking both the bootstrap javascript file and jquery in the header:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http@(Request.IsSecureConnection == true ? "s" : "")://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap-modal.js")"></script>
```

Comment: Have you initialized modal against #myModal beforehand?

Comment: fwiw 'http@(Request.IsSecureConnection == true ? "s" : ""):' can be removed '//' does this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659345/is-there-any-downside-for-using-a-leading-double-slash-to-inherit-the-protocol-i

Comment: according to http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html, doing $("#myModal").modal('show'); will initialize it and immediately invoke the show method. so I shouldn't have to initialize it before that. However, I have also tried doing $(document).ready(function() { $("#myModal").modal(); }); and would get the same error as soon as the page loads

Comment: Doing `$("#myModal").modal({ show: true })` will initialize it. Is your change event handler also within a $(document).ready block? Can you definitely confirm the bootstrap-modal.js is included correctly?

Comment: it is. although I've tried it in and out of one and I get the same error either way.

Comment: It is likely then that the bootstrap-modal file is not being loaded correctly. Can you verify it has been loaded using developer tools in the browser?

Comment: It appears to be. on Chrome's resources tab, it shows up under scripts and it is the correct file.

Comment: Hm. Can you also confirm you're not loading JQuery files multiple times, or loading bootstrap.js or bootstrap.min.js as well as bootstrap-modal? This can cause problems...

Comment: that was it. jquery had been loaded again at another spot on the page. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid loading JQuery files multiple times, or loading bootstrap.js or bootstrap.min.js as well as bootstrap-modal.js, as this can cause problems...