# $ is undefined jQuery and Bing Map API

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, bing-maps

So I am having an issue with the height of the infoboxes in Bing Maps API.  The content that I am loading in is going outside the box.  So I figured I would try to use jQuery to get the outerHeight and change the height of the div accordingly.

I seem to be running into an error with the error "$ is undefined".  I am pretty sure I am loading the library correctly and in the correct order.  Any ideas as to why I would still be getting this error?

```
<head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var infoBoxHeight = $('#infobox-info').outerHeight();
```

Then later I try to alert infoBoxHeight but I keep getting the "$ is undefined".  Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: 1.) Are there any errors in the JS console? 2.) Are you opening the HTML file from your hard drive (through the `file://` protocol?)

Comment: Yes I am running it locally right now.  And I tried adding http: to the address and same results.  As for checking if the scripts are loaded correctly,  I am not sure exactly what you mean.  In my developer tools error console the only error I get is $ is undefined.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Did you try this URI: `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js`

Comment: Locally I always use http:// instead of //. Try http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js in src parameter

Comment: In the other case I get an error "resource cannot be loaded" if I don't use http://

Comment: Firefox and that seemed to work.  Can you explain why that is needed?

Comment: It depends on the context. // seems to be related to the context. I've read if you set it into a html email // is not pointing to an URI and it doesn't work. I think the context changes if you're using it locally. In fact it supposed // works only in browsers supporting RFC 1808

Comment: Try using http:// and let us know.

Comment: @ErikPhilips `//` will be substituted by the scheme of the containing page (*file:///* in this case which obviously doesn't work).

Comment: Perhaps it is just a case of a "bad" error message. It may be a case that you are trying to get an element that doesn't yet exist in the DOM, and based on the snippet the attempt to get the height of the element would fire before the element is even in the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using http:// instead of //. I always did it but only because it didn't work sometimes in my development computer depending on the browser. Looking at this website I found an explanation:

A quote from [Synchro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/333340/synchro) from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12899126/603003) post:

> The more general explanation is that anonymous protocol URLs cannot
>   work in isolation; there must be a relevant context. In a typical web
>   page it's thus fine to pull in a script library that way, but any
>   external links should always specify a protocol. I did try one simple
>   test: //stackoverflow.com maps to file:///stackoverflow.com in all
>   browsers I tried it in, so they really don't work by themselves.

[Is there any downside for using a leading double slash to inherit the protocol in a URL? i.e. src="//domain.com"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659345/is-there-any-downside-for-using-a-leading-double-slash-to-inherit-the-protocol-i)

I hope it helps you. If you find I'm not contributing with this answer let me know.

Something else. I tried it locally and checked javascript console in Chrome, it doesn't work, the error is very clear:

**Failed to load resource file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js**
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined Index.html:8

It's looking locally the library.

Comment: Especially [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12899126/603003) in the linked question covers the file protocol.

Comment: Exactly, I copied the part of the answer that works for me. I never explored deeper why I had to do it and it became a habit. But in fact I checked again now at work and yes, if I don't use http:// in a local file it doesn't work, I get the same error resource can't be loaded (jquery)

Comment: Please include the author and a link the next time :) `//` will be substituted by the scheme of the containing page. If you run your file locally, `//` becomes `file:///ajax.googleapis.com`. On my PC, Chrome tries to load the script for several seconds (~10s) and then fails.

Comment: I did it with the link, sorry I didn't mention everything. I came up with the idea first and then I checked the website.

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend getting rid of

```
script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"
```

and inside your "text/javascript" put this

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('meta')[0].appendChild(jq);

jq.onload = procede;//make sure you don't type parenthesis

//i.e. 'procede()' runs function instantly
//     'procede' gives it a function to run when it's ready

...

function procede()
{
//jQuery commands are loaded (do your magic)


}
```