# Javascript not loading? Newbie here

Tags: javascript

When I open the html file in a browser the javascript doesn't work, I can't figure out why? The exact same code works in the codecademy prompts, but not when I launch it from files on my desktop.

HTML

```
<html>
      <head>
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400;300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet'>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="menu">

      <!-- Menu icon -->
      <div class="icon-close">
        <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/uber/close.png">
      </div>

      <!-- Menu -->
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Main body -->
    <div class="jumbotron">

      <div class="icon-menu">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        Menu
      </div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/* Initial body */
body {
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

/* Initial menu */
.menu {
  background: #202024 url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/uber/black-thread.png') repeat left top;
  left: -285px;  /* start off behind the scenes */
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 285px;
}

/* Basic styling */

.jumbotron {
  background-image: url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/uber/bg.png'); 
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
       -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
}

.menu ul {
  border-top: 1px solid #636366;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #636366;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

.menu a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.icon-close {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.icon-menu {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.icon-menu i {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Javascript

```
var main = function() {
  /* Push the body and the nav over by 285px over */
  $('.icon-menu').click(function() {
    $('.menu').animate({
      left: "0px"
    }, 200);

    $('body').animate({
      left: "285px"
    }, 200);
  });

  /* Then push them back */
  $('.icon-close').click(function() {
    $('.menu').animate({
      left: "-285px"
    }, 200);

    $('body').animate({
      left: "0px"
    }, 200);
  });
};


$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: Try clearing your cache.

Comment: Is your javascript the `app.js` file? Is this file in the same directory as this html page? What does your console say - any errors?

Comment: Every thing looks good but try: `$(function(){ main();});`

Comment: Looks like http: is missing from href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" and src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"

Comment: @BhasyakaruluKottakota Doesn't matter.

Comment: @PHPglue I cleared my cache and tried again but that did not work.

Comment: @user2853450 Can you upload your code to a server then give us the link?

Comment: Well, now you know it's not because your Browser saved your script in the cache.

Comment: As I mentioned above, what does your console say? That should point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Charlie It's not my code, just code for a beginner tutorial on codeacdemy, and no I can't. Don't have a server setup/don't know how to...I'm just starting.

Comment: @Goose "ReferenceError: $ is not defined app.js:26
The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol."

Comment: @RobertC http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While PHPglue is correct, and that you should place the closing `</div>` tag, that's not causing your JS to not execute. This console error, however:

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined app.js:26

Indicates that jQuery is not loading properly which means that this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Is somehow not working, and I think I know why...

Using `//` will [load the requested URL relative to the current page's scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659345/is-there-any-downside-for-using-a-leading-double-slash-to-inherit-the-protocol-i). Since you're viewing this from a browser locally, that scheme is `file://`. Consequently, you're not loading jQuery because it's requesting `file://ajax.googleapis...`.

So yes, my comment is party wrong. On a web server, where the scheme is either `http://` or `https://`, then using `//ajax.googleapis...` will be fine. On localhost, it's not.

Comment: Thank you, I actually solved it by adding the http a few minutes before you posted this, so yes, that did fix it. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing `</div>` tag:

```
<div class="jumbotron">

  <div class="icon-menu">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    Menu
  </div>
```

add

```
</div>
```

If you right click on your web page with Firefox and click `View Page Source`. You should see most HTML tag issues in red, if they are part of the source code. Of course, this won't work if your code was created with JavaScript.

Comment: adding an extra </div> under didn't help

Comment: That closing `</div>` is needed.

Comment: I meant it didn't solve my original question, but thanks, I will keep the div in.

Answer (score -4):

try `$document.ready(main());`

I don't know jQuery, so not sure if it needs to initiate the function with ()

Comment: Nope. That will run the function immediately, which defeats the purpose of the `.ready()` method (and concept). The idea is to pass a function pointer to be run when the document is ready, and not before.

Comment: No, you can pass an Anonymous function, or unexecuted function, which looks like a variable in JavaScript.

Comment: Ahh, good point.
That's what happens when you try to use a framework you don't know about.
Thx for the pointers

Comment: I am nut sure what those two slashes in the jQuery script mean, but you could try leaving them out. What I prefere is to place an 'alert("Hello World");' statement at the start of the script and then reload your page. If a dialog appears, there is something wrong with the script - otherwise, the problem is the html part (that seems to be fine)