# Why is AngularJS $route not working, pasted directly from the documentation?

Tags: angularjs

So I am wanting to learn more about how to use AngularJS $route as it seems to be the way to go for my single page application. Naturally, the best place to start is the documentation. They have a nice little Plunker for me to visually and hands-on see how it works. Next up, playing with it and making it my own. Before I can start messing with it to make it my own though, I need it working outside the Plunker: **so I made copies of each file and put them all in the same directory.**

However, I am getting the following errors:

> TypeError: angular is undefined script.js:3:0
>
> ReferenceError: angular is not defined index.html:14:4

The line for the first error is:

```
angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('head')).append(angular.element('<base href="' + window.location.pathname + '" />'));
```

and the line for the second error is:

```
angular.module('ngRouteExample', ['ngRoute'])
```

So to me it is obvious that it is not registering that AngularJS is referenced or something. Nothing about the code is breaking, it just doesn't recognize AngularJS. Why is this? How do I fix this?

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VTudWcprj9M6AOhC9MPN?p=preview)

[Original documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)

Comment: Send a link to the Plunkr that is failing since the one above does not result in an error.

Comment: @GabrielKohen The code that is failing is the exact code taken from that Plunker, as described in my question. Now you see my frustration.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Angular documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/downloading). Make sure you have included the Angular library in your index.html (or index.jsp/index.aspx).

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <title>My Angular App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ..**so I made copies of each file and put them all in the same directory.** -From my question. If I copied the code from index.html, I already have the reference to AngularJS.

Comment: @Christine268 If I'm looking at the example on the documentation site I see nowhere that the AngularJs files are included(They are probably included once for the whole page). Probably the file is not properly included as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: "Edit in Plunker" button. That is where I copied and pasted the code exactly from. The documentation is just where I got the Plunker from.

Comment: See an interesting discussion here about double slash here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659345/is-there-any-downside-for-using-a-leading-double-slash-to-inherit-the-protocol-i . It seems like the implicit protocol when you copied it locally was file://. That's why you needed to specify it explicitly to http:// on your local file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but the Plunker uses

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js
```

instead of

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js
```

Easily grazed over it. My bad. Thought Plunker, JSFIDDLE and all that use direct URLS.

Found error by starting to paste everything *back* in Plunker.