# what is the use of data-dojo-config in Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I started learning Dojo and came across how to include Dojo using CDN by below code which is defined in [Dojo Tutorial](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/hello_dojo/index.html)

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"
            data-dojo-config="async: true">
```

Here why they have missed `http`? Is that intentional, my program is not working unless I add `http` in my code.

Also what is the use of `data-dojo-config` attribute, I don't see any difference in my basic program even if I remove this attribute. When we need to use this attribute?

When I access some [other examples](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/animation/index.html), I see it differently:

```
data-dojo-config="isDebug: 1, async: 1, parseOnLoad: 1"
```

What are these properties, when to use them?

Comment: These are two separate questions. You should split them up.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659345/is-there-any-downside-for-using-a-leading-double-slash-to-inherit-the-protocol-i

Comment: @HannesJohansson, but the question is still related to the same code, but my main question is on `data-dojo-config`

Comment: It doesn't matter that they're related to the same code as long as the questions aren't related themselves. The `data-dojo-config` attribute has nothing to do with the script source protocol. Keep one question here and post the other as a new one, if you need to.

Comment: @HannesJohansson, will post a new question. Can you please answer the `data-dojo-config` question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

he `data-dojo-config` is the configurations paramenter for the the dojo loader and parser.
This is similar to the configurations parameters which you set for loading a database server for instance.

What is **dojo loader** and **parser**?

**dojo loader:** Loads the javascript modules ( javascript files ) synchronously or asynchronously.

**dojo parser:** The function of dojo parser is to parse and convert HTML code into dojo widgets wherever necessary.

The `data-dojo-config` can be set only at the start of the dojo application.

They cannot be changed during run time.

If they are not set than they take the **default** values.
The can be set to `1` (or `true`) or `0` (or `false`)

**isDebug** - sets the debug level for the dojo application. 
**async** - (default is 1) whether the dojo javascript modules should be loaded synchronously or asynchronously.
**parseOnLoad** - When set to true the dojo parser **automatically** parses the HTML document and converts data-dojo-elements to dojo widgets. If set to false than you need to explicitly call the dojo parser to parse the HTML document.

Comment: To further clarify, `data-dojo-config` is simply a declarative way of defining `dojoConfig`. See http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/hello_dojo/index.html and http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/dojo_config/index.html