# d3-graphviz basic example won't render

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, graphviz

I'm trying to use d3-graphviz in a very basic html page to render a graph for display.  However, nothing ever renders.  I worked my example down to the exact content of the "basic example" from the documentation and still nothing renders.  Here is my page content which is exactly the same as https://bl.ocks.org/magjac/a23d1f1405c2334f288a9cca4c0ef05b which is referenced from https://github.com/magjac/d3-graphviz

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@hpcc-js/wasm@0.3.11/dist/index.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-graphviz@3.0.5/build/d3-graphviz.js"></script>
<div id="graph" style="text-align: center;"></div>
<script>

d3.select("#graph").graphviz()
    .renderDot('digraph  {a -> b}');

</script>
```

If I load that file (chrome, firefox, or safari) then I just get a blank page.  I can throw in HTML above the `<div>` which renders, but the graph doesn't render.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code runs if I set up a local web server and access it. To do the same, you'll need to [set up a web server](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server).

[image: Example]

Comment: Ok, that is a little bit embarrassing.  Thanks for the pointer Hugo.  Followup question if you're familiar: what's special about the `src="//` syntax for the first import?  If I change that to `script="https://` like the others, then it doesn't work.  I'm trying to use d3-graphviz in a rails app and I would really like to be able to just drop those three dependencies on the server instead of referencing the externally hosted versions.

Comment: Ok, looks like the details is the `@hpcc-js` dependency which dynamically pulls down further wasm dependencies as needed.  My local server isn't hosting them so grabbing the API definitions (`index.min.js`) doesn't do me much good.  More details here: https://github.com/hpcc-systems/hpcc-js-wasm

Comment: For your question, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659345/is-there-any-downside-for-using-a-leading-double-slash-to-inherit-the-protocol-in. Using https:// fails likely because dev web servers usually only handle http://, and // will inherit that. For your Rails question, you can likely ask in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails.