# Slider for Slick.js is not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, slick.js

I followed all the steps how to do slider using slick but for some reason pictures are only stacking one on each other instead of becoming a slide
HTML code:

```
<!--Slider-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
<!--Main-->
    <main>

        <!--Slider-->
        <div class="container-fluid p-0">
            <div class="site-slider">
                <div class="slider-one">
                    <div>
                        <img src="assets/slide1.jpg" class="wid img-fluid" alt="Slika 1">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src="assets/slide2.jpg" class="wid img-fluid" alt="Slika 1">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src="assets/slide3.jpg" class="wid img-fluid" alt="Slika 1">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>


 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

This is my JS file:

```
$('.slider-one').slick({
    autoplay:true,
    autoplaySpeed:3000,
    dots:true
});
```

I have been trying to fix this problem but to no avail. So any help would be great. Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Did you add `slick.css` or `slick.min.css` and `slick-theme.css`?

Comment: I have added slick.min.css and slick.css via CDN

Comment: Did you add jquery ? Because you are using jquery. Is there an error in your console ?

Comment: @AmauryHanser I have just added it, still doesn't work

Comment: Slick requires jquery, [see the docs](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/). You can use a [CDN](https://code.jquery.com/), just like you did for slick, don't forget to add it **before** slick.js

Comment: @AmauryHanser there is this error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slick is not a function
    at main.js:1`

Comment: also it displays these 2 errors: `GET file://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` and `GET file://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Comment: ```slidesToShow : 2``` and ```slidesToScroll:1``` in setting slick js code

Comment: @frankfurt still an error

Comment: Your code is just fine. It seems the files aren't loading on your side but the code is correct. [See jsbin](http://jsbin.com/buqobugoka/edit?html,js,output), it's all your code.

Comment: Ok, it seems you are not running a server, but simply your file on your computer. Then change all your `src="//` with `src="https://`. You need to add the protocol `https:`

Comment: Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659345/is-there-any-downside-for-using-a-leading-double-slash-to-inherit-the-protocol-i#answer-12899126) for more infos about why it's not working.

Comment: @AmauryHanser IT WORKSS, thank youu soo much, write the answer and I will approve it, once again thank so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using double slash without specifying a particular protocol

When you load a resource by using a double slash `src="\\foo"`, you're not defining a protocol (http, https).
The script will load using the same protocol used to load the page itself.

If you are not using a web server, it won't work.
In your example, you can see that it's trying to load `file://foo"`, a file on your computer.

Adding the protocol, `https` in your case, will ensure that you'll load the resource successfully.